# Why isn't my network card discovered and enabled on boot?

Tags: boot, networking, network-manager

I'm running 21.04 server on Raspberry Pi CM3+ based device manufactured by Allo, their USBridge Signature.

On booting up the network card seems to be found but `lshw` reports it as disabled. Below is how it looks after I `sudo dhclient enx0017f700a9d6` to enable network:1, which is what I want to happen by default.

My question is what do I need to do to ensure that the boot process enables the device? No doubt my question makes it clear I'm a Linux noob, so please pitch your reply to my level.

Thanks

> *-network:0 DISABLED
> description: Ethernet interface
> physical id: 1
> bus info: usb@1:1.2
> logical name: enx0001f2fff397
> serial: 00:01:f2:ff:f3:97
> capabilities: ethernet physical
> configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_ether driverversion=5.11.0-1016-raspi firmware=CDC Ethernet Device link=no
> multicast=yes
>
> *-network:1
> description: Ethernet interface
> physical id: 2
> bus info: usb@1:1.3
> logical name: enx0017f700a9d6
> serial: 00:17:f7:00:a9:d6
> size: 1Gbit/s
> capacity: 1Gbit/s
> capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
> configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ax88179_178a driverversion=5.11.0-1016-raspi duplex=full
> ip=192.168.11.111 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s

Hi @chili555, Thanks for the response. Here's the results from `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

> This file is generated from information provided by the datasource. Changes
> to it will not persist across an instance reboot. To disable
> cloud-init's
> network configuration capabilities, write a file
> /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the
> following:
> network: {config: disabled}
>
> network:
> ethernets:
> eth0:
> dhcp4: true
> optional: true
> version: 2

Comment: I suspect that your netplan yaml file does not properly provide for enx0017f700a9d6 to start automagically. Let's have a look. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks for your help @chili555. Don't understand it of course - as you say, simply automagical

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is not a cloud-init instance. If that is incorrect, please stop and tell us in the comments.

Let’s follow the instructions in the file. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo “network: {config: disabled}”  >  /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg 
nano /etc/netplan/*.yaml
```

Replace the line eth0 with enx0017f700a9d6. Netplan is very specific about spacing, indentation, etc. so please proofread carefully twice.

Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x followed by Enter) the text editor nano.

Follow with:

```
netplan generate
netplan apply
exit
```

You should be all set.